# Conflicts between Ubuntu 20.04 packages and Debian 11 packages

Tags: apt, dependencies, debian

I'm having broken packages / conflicts between Ubuntu and Debian. In particular, Thunderbird and Perl cannot be updated.

For Perl, I get something like

```
$ sudo apt upgrade perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libclass-xsaccessor-perl : Depends: perl (< 5.30.1~) but 5.32.1-4+deb11u1 is to be installed
 libcommon-sense-perl : Depends: perl (< 5.30.1~) but 5.32.1-4+deb11u1 is to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.32.1-4+deb11u1) but 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
        Depends: perl-modules-5.32 (>= 5.32.1-4+deb11u1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libperl5.32 (= 5.32.1-4+deb11u1) but it is not going to be installed
```

My PPA list should be reasonable, in `sources.list.d/`:

```
debian.list
dropbox.list
graphics:darktable.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
jonaski-ubuntu-strawberry-focal.list
nodesource.list
sbt.list
spotify.list
```

and here is the content of `debian.list`

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org bullseye-security main
```

Any idea how to fix it, barring a reinstall? (which I would love to postpone until 22.04)

Comment: That is expected; they are different OSes.   My Ubuntu system is *impish* so my system is closer to the Debian *bookworm* (you could use *bullseye* here too) but they still differ.   They never really *align*.

Comment: "Any idea how to fix it, barring a reinstall" remove the debian ppa's? Ubuntu is NOT Debian and Debian is not Ubuntu.

Comment: Wow! thanks. I don't know how the debian repo appeared in my `sources.list.d` . I thought it was there by default.

Comment: The directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is an EMPTY directory on a Ubuntu install.  Anything found inside that directory was added post-install.

Comment: Thank you all. I've removed the debian PPA (who put it there?!?), and now `apt` doesn't complain about kept packages anymore. I guess I was lucky and just avoided a reinstall (my system boots properly and aptitude doesn't show anything broken). Phew

Comment: Too bad I've deleted the file, and I don't have recent `/etc` backups. The creation date could have given me a hint as to what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PPA list is *not* reasonable. You are not expected to mix in Debian repositories with Ubuntu repositories, because both operating systems are binary incompatible, even though Ubuntu is based of Debian.

Remove these PPA's asap. Using inadapted repositories may heavily damage a system, even leading to a need to reinstall. Only add third party repositories if 1) there is no other option and 2) they are explicitly indicated to work with the specific Ubuntu version that you use.

Comment: See comment above. I removed the Debian PPA, did `apt update`, and the system is booting properly and is stable for now. I'll reinstall if anything seems fishy.

Comment: Good to hear. Indeed: the system is not necessarily damaged yet after you added a wrong PPA. I will "moderate" that aspect of my answer. You will probably be fine with your system.

Comment: System works fine, I dodged a bullet here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are mixing sources from different distributions.

This is a bad idea and will create conflicts and all sorts of other problems.

Don't mix sources from other distros or even from different versions of Ubuntu.